# Two tables in left join both have id fields. Trying to pull id field from first database, but getting the second instead

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

Just updated my site from mysql_ to mysqli and broke a previously functioning query.

Im trying to pull the id from spins, as it increments by 1 each time, but I keep getting the player id instead, can someone tell me what Im doing wrong? I tried multiple variations of renaming spins to AS s.spins etc.

```
$query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM `spins` LEFT JOIN `players` ON `players`.id=`spins`.player ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 30");
```

Im using the following to call the spin id, but get the players id instead.

```
  $content.='<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically name the fields in your query, something like :

```
SELECT `spins`.id as spinsID FROM `spins` LEFT JOIN `players` ON `players`.id=`spins`.player ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 30"

$content.='<td>'.$row['spinsID '].'</td>';
```

Comment: Can be that specific if I am calling several fields from spins? Right now spins has 4 fields, and I am calling all of the for the results table.

Comment: It's good practice to get in the habit of specifying a table name as part of field references, using either the table name or `AS shortname` (e.g., `FROM spins AS s LEFT...`). That way you'll always have to explicitly decide what table a field comes from, at least if you're dealing with more than one table.

Comment: Suggest you call as many fields as you need and no more.  Eg SELECT `spins`.id as spinsID, `spins`.name as spinsName etc.  Using the * would work if the field names are unique, but they aren't and that is what is causing your problem.

Comment: this is what I cam up with, it works but its ugly as hell. There isnt a simpler way of doing this?

``$query=$db->query("SELECT spins.id AS spinsID,spins.wager,spins.multiplier,spins.player,spins.time,players.alias FROM `spins` LEFT JOIN `players` ON `players`.id=`spins`.player ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 30");``


UGH, cntrl+k isnt working for some reason

Comment: You could use select `spins`.* to shorten the query if you want to, I would only do this if you are using all the columns though